# Linq-like group by for sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

It seems like sql `group by` is more of aggregate functions (COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM, AVG).

```
select count(Id), Country 
from Customer
where Country <> 'CountryX'
group by Country
```

But do we have a linq-like query where we want to return all results grouped by a certain column, E.g. in linq I would do

```
id | title   | category | email         
------------------------------------------
1  | tname-1 | cat1     | test@example.com
2  | tname-2 | cat1     | test1@example.com
3  | tname-3 | cat2     | TEst@example.com
```

linq `group-by`:

```
var groupedBy = list.GroupBy(item => item.Email);
```

or even throw in some comparison

```
var groupedBy = list.GroupBy(item => item.Email, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

and a result will be something like:

```
key              | items
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
test@example.com | [{Id :1, Title : "tname-1", category: "cat1", email: "test@example.com" },{Id :3, Title : "tname-3", category: "cat2", email: "TEst@example.com" } ]
test1@example.com| [{Id :2, Title : "tname-2", category: "cat1", email: "test1@example.com" }]
```

but with sql I would definitely want to return only the subset of the columns, say `id`, `title` and `email`.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...